# Molecular weight of my 2-D gel

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, western-blot

I am a little confuse when I try to figure out the molecular weight of the marker on my gel. I used NuPage Novex 4-12% bis-tris gel and Mark12™ Unstained Standard as a marker. Could please someone help me to figure out the molecular weight of the marker on my gel? I find different images in internet and I am confuse.

[image: 2D gel example]

Comment: It looks you have everything except for insulin A and B chain. https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/LC5677

Comment: Please don't change your question as it makes the answer incorrect. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think. Does it help? Let me know if you need more information.

[image]